# how to separate string into different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a table with entries like this.

```
    MachineName
-----------------------

    Ab bb zecos
    a zeng
    zeng
    empty
```

4 rows in a table.

How can i seperate those 4 rows to get output like.

```
       M1       M2       M3
-----------------------------------
       Ab       bb      zecos
       a        zeng     NULL
       zeng     NULL     NULL
       NULL     NULL     NULL
```

Comment: This isn't by chance so you can apply tags to elements, would it?

Comment: @BradChristie Didn't get you!

Comment: As in you didn't understand the question? I'm asking if you're primary purpose is to apply tags to items (almost like a blog does to posts) and now you're trying to retrieve them back.

Comment: Maybe this post will help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

Comment: Create a temp table with M1, M2, M3 columns, get machine names, split names by spaces and insert row the in a new table

Comment: i have sting 
nt:865067021846160:2:8.5.05:1,1,20161010102239.000,18.580423,73.815948,549.700,0.28,33.6,11:101:100:0:0:0:FF:146:25} i want to separate by : into column

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using split function there is a function called ParseName which returns the specified part of the object which spilts the string delimated by **.** 
Please go through the [ParseName](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data) link which helped me in writing this query

```
Declare @Sample Table
(MachineName varchar(max))

Insert into @Sample
values 
('Ab bb zecos'),('a Zeng')


  SELECT 
  Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), ' ', '.'), 1)) As [M1]
 , Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), ' ', '.'), 2)) As [M2]
 , Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), ' ', '.'), 3)) As [M3]

  FROM  (Select MachineName from @Sample
  ) As [x]
```

Comment: I recall something about PARSENAME not allowing more than 4 items (since it's used for object names and 4 parts is the maximum length of an object identifier) - so you could use this as long as you remember that :)

Comment: Yeah thanks for reminding me but i think OP mentioned in his question having only 3 columns

Comment: perfect... this is what i also exactly want.. thanks a ton :)

Comment: If segments of the split are blank you may get no returned result for all of the segments. To avoid this I do the following (I use + as its not in the column but you can use any unused character): Replace(ParseName(Replace(DELADD.CONTACT_VALUE, CHAR(10), '+.+'), 3),'+','')

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIndex](@Delimiter varchar(20) = ' ', @Search varchar(max), @index int)
    RETURNS varchar(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
          DECLARE @ix int,
                      @pos int,
                    @rt varchar(max)

          DECLARE @tb TABLE (Val varchar(max), id int identity(1,1))

          SET @ix = 1
          SET @pos = 1


          WHILE @ix <= LEN(@search) + 1 BEGIN

                SET @ix = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Search, @ix)

                IF @ix = 0
                      SET @ix = LEN(@Search)
                ELSE
                      SET @ix = @ix - 1

                INSERT INTO @tb
                SELECT SUBSTRING(@Search, @pos, @ix - @pos + 1)

                SET @ix = @ix + 2
                SET @pos = @ix
          END

          SELECT @Rt = Val FROM @Tb WHERE id = @index
          RETURN @Rt     
    END
```

Use like so:

```
SELECT dbo.SplitIndex(' ', 'hello World', 1)
```

Combine that with Dems answer and you should be good to go

(Note it will return NULL if the specified index does not exist)

e.g.

```
SELECT dbo.SplitIndex(' ', 'Hello World', 3)
```

would return NULL because index 3 does not exist

Not sure what performance is like though, I just modified a table valued split function that I'd done so it might be worth rewriting to be more like the MySql version

Comment: Thank you, you saved me, this is the best solution. All above answer using PARSENAME has a drawback, of limitation no more then 4 values

Answer (score 4):

Use Parsename() function

```
with cte as(
    select 'Aria Karimi' as FullName
    Union
    select 'Joe Karimi' as FullName
    Union
    select 'Bab Karimi' as FullName
)

SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(FullName,' ','.'),2) as Name, PARSENAME(REPLACE(FullName,' ','.'),1) as Family from cte
```

Result

```
Name    Family
-----   ------
Aria    Karimi
Bab     Karimi
Joe     Karimi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Tmp TABLE (empid INT,joined nchar(10))

INSERT @Tmp SELECT 1,'1990, 1111' 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 2,'2000, 2222' 

INSERT @Tmp SELECT 3,'1993, 3333' 

INSERT @Tmp SELECT 4,'1899, 4444' 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 5,'1999, 5555' 

INSERT @Tmp SELECT 6,'2001, 6666 ' 


--Using PARSENAME 

SELECT empid, joined,
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(joined,',','.'),2) join1, 
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(joined,',','.'),1) join2 
FROM @Tmp
```

Answer (score -7):

If you are programming in C++, please do:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main () {
string machine[12];
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if (machine[i] == "")
        machine[i] = "NULL";
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << setw(10) << machine[i] << setw(10) << machine[i+1] << setw(10) << machine[i+2] << endl;
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: No c++ tags on this post, isn't this a bit of a guess?

Comment: Do you *honestly* propose solving a database query by extracting *every* record from the DB, processing it in C++, and then pushing everything back to the DB?  ***Really***?

Comment: Sounds like a horror story from TheDailyWTF to me :)