# splitting charecter string with required column length sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am having table with column contains  rows

```
100X200X300
1000X2000X3000
```

I want to split it as

```
A           B             C
100        200           300
1000       2000          3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You answer is here: [how to separate string into different columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185318/how-to-separate-string-into-different-columns)

with the limitation that you would not need to split the sting into more that 4 columns

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48354/1

```
CREATE TABLE sample (MachineName VARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO sample
VALUES ('100X200X300'),
    ('1000X2000X3000')

SELECT Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), 'X', '.'), 1)) AS [M1],
    Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), 'X', '.'), 2)) AS [M2],
    Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(MachineName), 'X', '.'), 3)) AS [M3]
FROM (
    SELECT MachineName
    FROM sample
    ) AS [x]
```