# Sybase Split Data on Delimeter

Tags: sql, select, sybase

I have a column which stores data as

```
"George|Michael|15-06-1984|New York"
```

Expected Output is

```
FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME DOB        CITY
George     Michael   15-06-1984 NEW YORK
```

How to split this data on `delimiter` - `|` while calling a `select` query in `Sybase` ?

Comment: It's funny.  The George Michael that I know of is quite a bit older:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Michael.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a procedure:

Here is a good solution:

> [sa_split_list system procedure replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20816801/12366261)

Or you can use function called ParseName:

> [ParseName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11186128/12366261)

Of course, you have to change your delimeter in `select statement` from `,` to `|`.